# UIAlertView exclusiveTouch on buttons iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

On iOS 7, when UIAlertView is presented, its buttons seem to automatically have `exclusiveTouch=YES` set. This way, if you simultaneously press more than one button on alert view, nothing terribly will happen.

This is not the case on iOS 8. When I present UIAlertView with 2 buttons. And I press these 2 buttons at the same time, the app freezes.

I cannot access the `UIButton`s on that `UIAlertView`. I cannot access any of the subviews of `UIAlertView` for that matter.
`alertView.subview` returns empty array, no matter in which part of the lifecycle I call it.

Comment: please, add your code to description. Also for iOS8 you can use UIAlertViewController.

Comment: I don't see the need to post the code. I have expresses a statement that buttons inside an UIAlertView have 'exclusiveTouch' boolean property invariably set to NO. This statement is either true or false. I see this as a rather theoretical question. Besides, I am using my own subclass of UIAlertView which would ostensibly add to the complexity of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to find a solution to the problem. I implement the UIAlertView's delegate method:

```
-(void)didPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView
{
    UIView *view = ((UIApplication*)[UIApplication sharedApplication]).keyWindow.rootViewController.presentedViewController.view;
    [self setExclusiveTouchForView:view];
}

-(void) setExclusiveTouchForView:(UIView*)view
{
    for (UIView *subview in view.subviews) {
        subview.exclusiveTouch = YES;
        [self setExclusiveTouchForView:subview];
    }
}
```

At first it was confusing to see that neither of all the subviews inside the `view` variable is of class `UIButton` or `UIControl`.

It is not actually necessary to set `exclusiveTouch` property on **all** of the subviews. But I posted it like this to reduce code complexity.

It works fine. App no longer freezes when both of `UIAlertView`'s buttons are pressed at the same time. Only one of the presses is accepted.

Comment: You should really be using uialertcontroller not uialertview in iOS 8

Comment: My app supports both iOS7 and iOS8 and this currently seems like the best way to avoid IF-THEN code multiplication.